# Wicket: Get notified when no checkbox is selected anymore

Tags: java, wicket, web-frameworks, wicket-7

This is part of a Wicket GUI (Wicket 7.6.0) which is acting as a front end to display some database entries.

On this  specific page we have a form where a user can search for entries by specifiyng eg. a start date, end date etc. to limit the results. After hitting the button the search entries are displayed below this search form.

These results are displayed using a Wicket `DataTable` with pagination. The entries in that table have a check box. This is implemented by a custom `CheckBoxPanel` (extended from `Panel`) to which a `Check` instance (`org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Check`) is added.

Now, I want to react to each select **and** unselect of a checkbox. The reason for this is that we want to keep track of the items of the selection even on pagination in a second list.

I added the `AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior` to the group (see source of method `addCheckboxes` below). This works as long as at least one checkbox is selected - for every click on a checkbox the debug statement is printed.

But when the last checkbox is unselected the `onUpdate()` method is **not** called, despite the fact that an AJAX call is made (verified by using *Firefox Developer Tools*). The request payload is `group%3Aactions=`. When I select an item the request payload is e.g.: `group=check4&group%3Aactions=`.

**My question is:** Is there a way to get notified if none items are selected anymore? This is needed to keep the before mentioned "second list" in sync.

A solution does not need to use AJAX, a classic POST solution would also be ok.

````
private void addCheckboxes() {
    System.out.println("addCheckboxes called!");
    selectedModel = new CollectionModel<FaultModel>(new ArrayList<FaultModel>());
    group = new CheckGroup<FaultModel>("group", selectedModel);
    group.onSelectionChanged();
    group.setRequired(Boolean.TRUE);

    CustomCheckGroupSelector<FaultModel> groupSelector = new CustomCheckGroupSelector<>("groupselector", rows.isEmpty());

    RemarkModalWindow remarkModal = new RemarkModalWindow("remarkModal", selectedModel);
    IndicatingAjaxButton actionButton = new ActionButton<FaultModel>("execute", this, remarkModal, rows.isEmpty());

    DefaultDataTable<?, String> table = TableFactory.getTable2(CustomType.FAULT, rows, page);
    group.add(table);
    group.add(groupSelector);
    group.add(remarkModal);
    group.add(actionButton);

    group.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() {
        @Override protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println("!! onUpdate !! Adding selected items to second list.");
        }
    });

    add(group);
}
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that you have set `group.setRequired(Boolean.TRUE);` so not having any selection at all actually is not a valid state which is why the `onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target)` of your AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior is not called.

You could either set `group.setRequired(false);` or override the `onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, RuntimeException e)` method in your AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior, which gets called when (among other errors) no elements are selected while the form component is required.